# How do natives understand a word with multiple meanings?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, reading-comprehension

When I was reading, I noticed that some adjectives can be understood in different possible ways.

For example, the word “stark” in the sentence **though he appeared the image of stark and uncompromising severity**.

If looked up in a dictionary, “stark” can be explained as “complete and total”, or “unpleasant;real, and impossible to avoid”. Both meanings seem to fit in the sentence.

So I am wondering, how to tell the exact meaning of a word in a sentence? How can I know I’m not misunderstanding the text?

Comment: side note: that's not a complete sentence, please edit your question to add the entire sentence. Also, I do not see how exactly "complete and total" fits in that sentence.

Comment: The two meanings are related and both apply. Native speakers look at context. What do you do in your own language?

Answer (score 1):

The quote is from a rather long sentence (105 words) by Virginia Woolf in "To the Lighthouse":

[Library of Congress sample quote](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/enhancements/fy0642/2005004201-s.html)

It's part of a description of a six-year-old child. The meaning of the sentence is that the child had an active internal mental life, made up of images that he was sentimental about; that is put in contrast with his "stark" and "severe" external appearance.

I think this sense of "stark" fits here:

[American Heritage Dictionary "stark" (2b)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stark)

> 2.b. Severe or unmitigated; harsh or grim